# FP-growth - Items in a transaction must be unique

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have run the code in my computer and with Frequent pattern mining. I use the FP-growth, but the pyspark throws an error and I have no idea how to solve it, so can somebody using the pyspark help me?

First I get the data

```
data = sc.textFile(somewhere)
```

This step has no error
and then

```
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
```

Next is

```
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
```

which throws an error

```
An error occurred while calling o19.trainFPGrowthModel.:org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Items in a transaction must be unique but got WrappedArray(,  ,  A,  ,  Seq,  0xBB20C554Ack,  0xE6A8BA01Win,  0x7D78TcpLen,  20).
```

My data looks like this

```
 transactions.take(1)

[[u'03/07',
  u' 10',
  u' 22',
  u' 04.439824',
  u' 139',
  u' 1',
  u' 1',
  u' spp_sdf',
  u' SDFCombinationAlert',
  u' Classification',
  u' SenstiveData',
  u' Priority',
  u' 2',
  u' PROTO',
  u' 254',
  u' 197.218.177.69',
  u' 172.16.113.84']]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, exception you get is pretty much self-explanatory. Each bucket passed to FP-growth has to contain a set of items so there can be no duplicates. So for example this is not a valid input:

```py
transactions = sc.parallelize([["A", "A", "B", "C"], ["B", "C", "A", "A"]])
FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
## Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.trainFPGrowthModel.
## ...
## Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
##   Items in a transaction must be unique but got WrappedArray(A, A, B, C).
```

You have ensure that items are unique before pass these downstream.

```py
unique = transactions.map(lambda x: list(set(x))).cache()
FPGrowth.train(unique, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
```

**Notes**:

- it is a good idea to `cache` data before running `FPGrowth`.
- subjectively it is not the best choice for the data you use.

Comment: yes, I found the root of the problem, I will ensure that the uniqueness of the data , and thank you very much.

Comment: another problem, how I save the result to local file?i have been try the saveAsTextFile() and write(), but it return an error,thank you.

Comment: is there an algorithm that could handle non-unique items ?